# htaccess for two domains using one hosting account?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My setup is thus: 
One hosting account with 2 separately purchased domains. 
one domain has no htaccess file but the other one does. The htaccess file doesn't seem to work at all. Is it possible to have the one domain without htaccess use the configuration settings on go daddy for , let's say, 404 pages and then the other domain that is WITH htaccess to completely IGNORE those settings and only listen to the htaccess rewrites?

*I will mention also, the second domain works without having to type the primary domain address in the url. Only thing I want is to add a htaccess file with the proper 404 redirect for the secondary domain and the hiding of .php extension of the url. I read in another question that the problem was absolute paths - i tried both absolute and relative in the error documents redirect section.

Comment: Is that two websites or one site under two different domains? The latter would be bad in terms of SEO. You should use a 301 redirect from secondary domains to the primary domain in that case.

Comment: they are two unrelated websites with each their own 404 pages. The first domain already works with 404 just fine, but the second domain points to the first domain's 404 even though the htaccess tells it otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if both domains are pointed to different directories in the server configuration. The Apache configuration using an `.htaccess` file is always for this directory (and all subdirectories) where the `.htaccess` is stored.

I don't know about GoDaddy, but my hoster provides a menu to change the path for each domain.

You can also point both domains to the same directory. In that case you need some domain detection (e.g. via mod_rewrite) to configure each domain separately. I wouldn't do that if that were two distinguished sites.

You can't ignore server settings that are already set. But maybe you can overwrite them. (Which properties can be overwritten, depends on the global server settings.)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my-own-not-found.html

# could also point to your homepage
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, i did that to my htaccess and placed the htaccess file in the domain directory (the one i need to listen to this file) and it still didn't work...:(

Comment: @user1366254 Mail the customer support…